# Cronjob runs when manually started, but not on each reboot

Tags: ubuntu, cron, webmin

trying to program a cron job

here it is,

```
@reboot lynx -dump ft-server > /dev/null
```

When I run the job manually via webmin, all is well, does what it is supposed to, no error. But when I reboot the system, it does nothing.

Help!

Comment: check out the end of this article http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/howto-linux-unix-start-restart-cron/

Comment: What do you have in the `/var/log/syslog` file? Use `grep -i cron`, since some lines are in all caps: `CRON`...

Comment: @RobertPeters: What specifically do you think is useful there?

Comment: @sarnold "If you are using Debian or Ubuntu Linux use the following commands to ensure that the service remains enabled after a reboot:"

Comment: @RobertPeters: Thanks. I've never seen a system that _didn't_ have `cron` enabled at boot, so the whole page seemed off-kilter.

Comment: @JonYork after reboot run this command and make sure cron is running "ps -ef | grep cron | grep -v grep"

Comment: @RobertPeters This is what your command returned
"root 1102 1 0 20:18 ? 00:00:00 cron

Comment: btw, still didn't run the job

Comment: Hum...cron is running. Try running cron with a simpler command like "touch /tmp/test_cron.txt". That will let you know if it's cron or something with your command (like environment variables)

Comment: alright, so that touch works...

Comment: Got it to work!

I changed my command to this "php -q /mnt/server/seals/index.php"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of trying to make lynx got to the website that was hosted locally, All I had to do was run the php file.

my command was not running because apache wasn't up yet.